# On the database tab under create database there is a message "No Privileges"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am on a Windows 8.1, 64 bit computer. I have XAMPP 5.6.3 installed. Everything was working correctly up until yesterday. I went into phpMyAdmin to create a new database. When I went to the Database Tab; under Create New Database, the words `No Privileges` were there. I tried to find the Privileges tab but can't find it. How do I fix this?

Comment: I suspect you're no longer logging in as your usual user. Are you being prompted for a username and password? If not, please check the phpMyAdmin configuration (normally in `config.inc.php` but I don't know XAMPP) and verify the user and password fields. Try connecting via command line client and see if you can create the database there. Have you changed the password on the account recently?

Comment: Thank you for staying with this. I was in need to get this going and noticed a updated Xmapp so I followed the instruction for that and I am back up. I will keep your comments because this might happen again. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to go in Privilege in menubar and check your permission user. Try to use the root user!
"If my response help you pls don't forget to check the flag

Comment: Answers should only be accepted [if they answer the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256564/477563), not just because they're helpful.

Comment: There is no "privileges" on the menu bar. I have Database, SQL, Status, Export, Import, Settings, Variables, Charset and Engins